# How to exclude yourself from NEW (2014) Google Analytics traffic using cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

Google has completely changed analytics, ga.js has been replaced by analytics.js and non of the old methods listed below work anymore:

**Method1:**

```
<body onLoad="javascript:pageTracker._setVar('test_value');">
```

**Method2:**

```
<body onLoad="javascript:_gaq.push(['_setVar','test_value']);">
```

**Method3:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setVar', 'exclude_me']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    // etc...
</script>
```

**The new GA snipplet looks like this:**

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');  // Creates a tracker.
    ga('send', 'pageview');     // Sends a pageview.
</script>
```

I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) but I couldn't figure out how to set a variable that can be used in the filter, to exlude internal traffic from Google Analytics.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While link-only answers are generally frowned upon this *is* covered in the Universal Analytics documentation, so I suggest you look at [Universal Analytics - Advanced Configuration - User Opt Out](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout).

UPDATE

Sorry, missed that last sentence about filtering. It is possible to filter via custom dimensions (but only after you created them in the backend), so you'd need to follow these steps:

Create a custom dimension - let's call it "opt-out" - in the property settings.

Send a value for that dimension via the trackingcode:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'true'
});
```

Where the dimension is indicated by the literal string "dimension" and the numeric index (which is shown in the custom dimension dialog in the property settings).

Then chose a view, go to filters, choose new filter/advanced/exclude, choose custom dimensions "opt-out" in the filter field and "true" in filtern pattern  (presumably you have done the same with custom vars before, so it should be familiar).

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best way to prevent internal traffic being sent to GA altogether, but it does not explain how to have it sent and filter it with the new system. However, as the question was mainly focused on filtering internal traffic, if I don't get a better answer, I'll accept this one.

Comment: Sorry, missed that last sentence, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @TheRebel - can you confirm that this approach works for you? I have a custom dimension defined that has been in use for a while, so I know it's active, but it is not listed as an option in the "Filter Field" list for custom filter types.

Comment: It did work when I accepted the answer, not sure if it works now. Lately I usually just set a ga-disable cookie in the browser: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout

Comment: @AndrewChase, by now I'm not sure myself if it works, because per documentation filters should not work on empty fields - we have discussed this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267940/create-a-google-analytics-view-filter-that-excludes-hits-with-missing-fields/29275125#29275125, But you should see custom dimension in custom filters (I certainly do).

Answer (score 4):

You should add it as a set call, after the create call and before a send call.

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'internal');
```

So in your case,

```
<body onLoad="javascript:ga('set','dimension1','internal');">
```

This will then associate that dimension (1) with the rest of the send calls made on that page. To add a filter on a view, you'll need to have the dimension setup already, then select a "Custom Filter" > "Exclude" > Filter Field should be set to your custom dimension (usually at the very end of the list).

And while that method is preferred as you can add or remove filters later on to capture that traffic, you can also use the [opt-out setting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout) to remove that traffic:

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXX-Y'] = true;
```

Where `UA-XXXX-YY` is your account ID.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the [upgrade documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs) that you'd need to set some custom variables and use those in creating some filters ([see this post](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/03/11/goodbye-to-exclude-filters-google-analytics/)).

That said, it seems fairly complicated to me.  An easier solution from my perspective is to use a server-side language which outputs the Google Analytics code only if the user is not in an exclude list.

Your tags don't provide a server-side language (ok, javascript can be used server-side, but I'm not thinking that's where you're at with this question), so can't provide a demo for you in a language I know you have, but in PHP, I would write it like this:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {?>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');  // Creates a tracker.
    ga('send', 'pageview');     // Sends a pageview.
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is a quite good workaround! It could actually also be done on client side. Set a cookie in the browser(s) that we don't want to follow and then only run this GA snipplet when the cookie doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I almost gave up searching for answer, but then found [this section in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout).

1. Make yourself a dummy page on your site. For example:
   www.yourdomain.com/exclude-traffic.html
2. Add in <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> in head, so the page wont be indexed.
3. Add script above your tracking code inside the head tag. Make sure you update UA-XXXXXXXX-Y values. You can check your GA code in Admin -> Tracking info -> Tracking code
4. Add link inside body tag.
5. Open the page with your browsers and click on the link. (You might be using Firefox and Chrome etc.)

Final result:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Remove My Internal Traffic from Google Analytics</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <script>
            // Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
            var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y';

            // Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
            var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
                window[disableStr] = true;
            }

            // Opt-out function
            function gaOptout() {
                document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
                window[disableStr] = true;
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'domainname.com'); //now its changed to auto
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Remove My Internal Traffic from Google Analytics</h1>
    <p><a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Click here to opt-out of Google Analytics</a></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is it still working today? It doesn't work when I run it from my Nexus 5 cellphone.