# Create a Google Analytics view filter that excludes hits with missing fields

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have a mobile iOS app that uses Google Analytics.

Recently I have been receiving hits in my reports that are clearly not coming from my app. I guess someone must be using my tracker ID (I hope, by mistake).

So I've been trying to create a filtered view that doesn't include this traffic. My first approach was to create an include filter on the applicationID field, hoping that would filter out any hit that doesn't have the right applicationID. When using the Google Analytics iOS SDK, this field is always set with the app bundle identifier, so it is highly improbable - if not impossible - that a hit sent by mistake by someone else will have the correct value.

It didn't work, and after wondering why for days, I just found out. The document about view filters (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162) actually says : "*Fields specified in a filter must exist in the hit and not be null in order for the filter to be applied to that hit*". So I can't have filters on missing fields, which is a problem because those unwanted hits I'm receiving seems to have all of their fields empty.

Which leads me to ask : Has anyone ever had this problem before ? And if yes, what is your approach ?

Currently I am using an unfiltered view with a custom segment that does the work (because the filtering of empty fields is doable using segments). But I would like to have a filtered view on which I could apply *real* segments.

Thanks for your insights

Comment: This sounds like the classic "can't prove a negative" problem.  If I understand you correctly, all you have to do is reverse the filter condition. Instead of trying to include traffic where applicationID doesn't exist, only include traffic where it DOES exist (and for good measure has a certain value, if it's a static value or if you can make a pattern)

Comment: Well, yes and know. I know that I can either only include the traffic with the right applicationID, or exclude all the traffic with a wrong applicationID. The problem is that google analytics filters will not be applied on empty fields. So wether I use an include or an exclude filter will not change anything, hits with an empty applicationID field will go through no matter what.

Comment: OH i get what you mean now. okay so what about.. make the include if applicationID=[whatever] and then make a 2nd filter after that, that just excludes everything using a field that will always be there (like ip address or something).  that way if the first filter doesn't positively catch it, the 2nd filter excludes the traffic

Comment: Well, I can try that. To be honest I think that Google Analytics won't differentiate a "positive" match from a match just because the filter wasn't applied, and the exclude filter will end up being applied every time or never. The documentation on the matter (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034832) is really not helpful. I will try it anyway, but since I can't test this configuration on existing data, I will have to wait a few days to see if it works. I will come back here with the result.

Comment: My idea is under the assumption that the first filter will be **ignored** if `applicationID` doesn't exist, and that assumption is based on the last statement in the paragraph you quoted on first link: *"[..]then any filters acting on Hostname will be ignored and the hit will be processed as if there was no filter."*

Comment: So IOW I think the logic would be if `transactionID` exists (and matches pattern if you add that), then include the traffic, and then the exclude would get ignored, because the include filter already returned true.  But if `transactionID` doesn't exist, the first filter is ignored and so the 2nd filter is eval'd and just excludes everything. But yeah for sure test it!

Comment: So in the case of a missing applicationID, only the second always-exclude filter will be applied. I agree with that. I'm not so sure about the other case though. If there is a match with the first include filter, will the exclude filter will then be applied ? If there is multiple include filters, the doc says that they will all be applied, and they must all match or the hit will be ignored. An exclude filter following an include filter is undocumented... My only solution at this point is to try :-) Thanks a lot anyway !

Comment: Just for the record if anyone else reads this, I am opened to any solution that filters out unwanted traffic, it doesn't have to be using this applicationID field.

Comment: i would advise you create a separate view to test on though, just in case it does pop the exclude

Comment: Don't worry, that's what I'm doing :) I also keep the default unfiltered view as recommended by Google.

Comment: Well unfortunately it didn't work, as I suspected everything was excluded. The solution from Eike Pierstorff did work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a mobile view to test with, but based on web tracking the following seems to work:

- Create a new filter, custom, advanced
- Field A : Application ID
- Extract A : (.*)
- Field B : leave empty
- Output to : Custom field 1
- Constructor : $A1
- Make sure that "Field A required" and "Override Output Field" are checked
- Create a second filter, custom, include
- Filter field : Custom Field 1
- Filter Pattern : Your application bundle ID (e.g : com.mycompany.MyAppName)

It seems advanced filters do recognize if a field is empty via the "Field Required" setting. So the custom field is set only when the field is not empty, and you can subsequently use a second filter to include only visits that have the field set (thereby excluding hits that haven't the field set)

To illustrate my less than brilliant instructions, the following worked for me:

[image: First Filter]

---

[image: Second Filter]

Comment: Great solution ! I made some small changes to your solution though and I took the liberty of editing your answer. I think the changes I made make the answer more general and usable. Thanks !

Comment: Don't know if my edit didn't work or was rejected. Is there any way to know by the way ? If it was rejected, sorry but I edited again.