# Exclude hostname "(not set)"

Tags: google-analytics

I am wondering if is possible to exclude '(not set)' records from the host-name field? All guides suggests to include the known hosts but with this approach a lot of them can be missed (ex. 'hidemyass.com', 'webcache.googleusercontent.com', etc..). Any idea how to implement this filter? Bellow option does not seems to work:

[image]

Comment: I do not think the requests send the "not set" value, I'm pretty sure this is added by the interface and the hostname value is just empty. You might try  this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267940/create-a-google-analytics-view-filter-that-excludes-hits-with-missing-fields/29275125#29275125 and adapt it to an empty hostname field.

Comment: You should know, that this approach is a bit dangerous. There are hit types (event, transaction) which possibly don't have the host set at all. So you could filter more data then you expect to.

Comment: Thank you both for great tips. I think the solution is to check the length of the hostname field. In my case I configured the hit to be included in case where hostname length varies between 1 and 60 characters. Solution: custom filter -> include -> hostname -> ^.{1,60}$

Comment: michaelsinner: in my case all the ("not set") record resulted in spam keywords so it was safe to remove them. Nevertheless I will rethink about filtering spam landing pages and keywords dimension.

Comment: You can try as solution Include Only Hostname (yourwebsite.com) or regExp (*.yoursite.com). And you will Exclude all ("not set") hostname.