# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol not safe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

For example we have this call :

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-1&cid=test&t=event&ec=authentication&ea=logout&el=&ev=1
```

This works like a charm, so it could be used in ASP MVC in the controller for example..

BUT :
isn't this dangerous the way google makes it easy to perform this call?
no authentication, nothing! everybody can use this way of communicating with your GA Account if they know your hostname (duh) and your UA-id (javascript is visible for everyone).. Even if you wouldn't allow traffic from other hosts then your own, it's easily manipulated by adding the hostname parameter in the call..

So my question is :
Can you avoid abuse?

Comment: Why a downvote without proper comment? This is a good question IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dangerous. It is also unavoidable.

The measurement protocol is not some "extra" to GA, it is what the clientside tracking code builds upon. In other words, if your measurement protocol calls had to be authenticated, your web tracking calls would need to be authenticated, too. Implementing transparent authentication in a public piece of javascript does not really work.

If you use GA for measurement protocol calls only you can include a custom dimension in your calls, and then set a view filter to dismiss all calls that do not contain the parameter (requires a [bit of a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267940/create-a-google-analytics-view-filter-that-excludes-hits-with-missing-fields/29275125#29275125) since typically filters do not work on missing fields).  That's as safe as it gets. The same technique will not work for the web (although it might work in a limited way against referral spam that uses the measurement protocol) because the custom dimension value will have to be embedded in your page.

Comment: I'm aware i could use filters but that's a bit unclean in my eyes.. So if I get it right , someone would be able to create a batch (limited to 20) and run it 24h a day with just enough delay between the 20 events to avoid beeing marked as spam.. ?

Comment: Basically, yes. The same guy would be able to set up a script that calls your site periodically, so there is no "extra" danger compared to the usual problem with webtracking.  The really annoying thing with GA is not that somebody can send extra calls (that happen with all tracking systems), it's that you cannot remove junk data once it's been collected.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input , you've answered my question like i hoped it would :)

Comment: Would you prefer the GTM way , firing a tag (event in this case) when certain things happen, or the MP way and firing it serverside

Comment: GTM is a lot simpler, server-side via MP is a lot more reliable. You'd need to choose were your priorities are, for most use cases GTM is "good enough" and a lot easier to implement.

Comment: I already use GTM, no problem just wondering if there were differences in reliability :)